# Using closure with event arguments in typescript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, closures

I'm trying to implement a debounce function using closure with typescript React.
The problem is that it seems it's made a new reference of the function every time when I try to pass an event argument. So I think it has something to do with passing and executing `_handleScroll`... Can anyone help me?

**This doesn't work**

```js
  const _handleScroll = (e: UIEvent<HTMLElement>): (() => void) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let prev = Date.now();
    const debounce = 500; // 500ms
    let counter = 0;

    return () => {
      const now = Date.now();
      if (prev - now > debounce) {
        prev = now;
        setScrollHeight(e.currentTarget.scrollTop);
      }
      ++counter;
      console.log("@@@", { now, prev, counter }); // result: counter: 1, 1, 1,...
    };
  };

...

    <div
      className="h-full overflow-y-auto"
      onScroll={(e) => _handleScroll(e)()}
    >

...
```

**But this works**

```js
  const _handleScroll = (): (() => void) => {
    // e.stopPropagation();
    let prev = Date.now();
    const debounce = 500; // 500ms
    let counter = 0;

    return () => {
      const now = Date.now();
      if (prev - now > debounce) {
        prev = now;
        // setScrollHeight(e.currentTarget.scrollTop);
      }
      ++counter;
      console.log("@@@", { now, prev, counter }); // result: counter: 1, 2, 3,...
    };
  };
...

<div className="h-full overflow-y-auto" onScroll={_handleScroll()}>

...
```

Comment: I tested your code. And I just wonder how does the code work like this, too. If there are any explanations tag me too, please.

Comment: @HumanoidMk.12 So I want to some action which is calling `setHeight` whenever scroll event is fired but I don't want to execute every 10ms if user make a really fast scroll move. So I'd like to fire this event, only if  it's more than `500ms`  which is set as `debounce` in my code

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be helpful if I understand what you want.

> useRef is for avoiding re-render.

```
let prev = useRef<number>();
  let height = useRef<number>(0);
  const _handleScroll = () => {
    const now = Date.now();
    const debounce = 500; // 500ms

    if (!prev.current) {
      ++height.current;
      prev.current = Date.now();
      setScrollHeight(e.currentTarget.scrollTop);
    }
    if (!!prev.current && now - prev.current > debounce) {
      prev.current = Date.now();
      setScrollHeight(e.currentTarget.scrollTop);
      ++height.current;
    }
  };

<div className="h-full overflow-y-auto" onScroll={_handleScroll}>
```

_handleScroll will be activated every scrolling but state updated 500ms.

Comment: Originally I used `useRef` actually and as you wrote it works fine. But I just want to try closure without `useRef` but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In second block of code that you provided when you were passing handle scroll like `onScroll={_handleScroll()}` you are passing **returned value of that function**.
But in first block of code you're passing `onScroll={_handleScroll}` you're actually passing **reference** of that function. and **every time your component rerenders the reference passed to the div will change**
if you want to prevent that use **[useCallback](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) hook** it's similar to useEffect you wrap your function in it and pass your dependencies in [] it baiscally caches your function reference and only changes it when your dependencies change
Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately using `useCallback` gives me the same result :/

Comment: i think your problem is that when this component rerenders you lose your scrollTop value am i right? if that's you're problem you can wrap your entire component in useMemo i had similar problem where i was zooming into a chart and parent rerender was reseting my zoom useMemo fixed it